# Install R packages problem using RStudio Package Manager

Tags: r, rstudio

I tried to install R packages using RStudio Package Manager using the following code:

```
install.packages("dplyr", type = "source")
```

and

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

and it gives the following error:

> Error in install.packages : invalid version specification 'r56550'

What should I do? I tried to google the error but nothing comes up. I have tried to delete and reinstall R and RStudio but i still received the error. I tried to download both the existing binary and the source file and neither ways worked. I tried to install different packages and repeated in both R and Rstudio and nothing worked.

Thank you!

Update 1: I'm using R version 4.0.5 and RStudio version 1.4.1106. I have also downloaded Rtools40 according to the instruction in the following website: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. I'm using Windows. By 'R Manager' I meant the package manager console in RStudio.

Update 2: I'm not sure if there is no network issue or proxy. If I download the packages directly through the CRAN mirror, then it works. But we are trying to download packages in an offline environment, that's why I need RStudio Package Manager.

Comment: What is R Manager?  Also, can you show _exactly_ what command you ran?

Comment: Ok,  now we have the command.  Next, what _operating system_?  Why `"source"`? Many systems have binaries to install too.  And I presume by 'R Manager' you meant the package manager console in RStudio?  Did you by chance also consider trying `install.packages("dplyr", type = "source")` straight in R?

Comment: Ok, you finally said you use Windows. Why can you not just download the existing binary, so omit `type="source"` and just say `install.packages("dplyr")` ?  Also, the error is highly unusual. Are you sure there is no network issue or proxy?

Comment: Hi Dirk, I have edited my questions to answer your questions. Thank you so much for your help! I am really at loss. I don't even know what r56550 is.

Comment: My guess is that this is a bug in the RStudio Package Manager, which you should report to RStudio: apparently there’s a package which depends on a specific R revision (r56550) which is unusual but not unheard of, and the RStudio Package Manager fails to understand this requirement. Before reporting the error you should find out which package installation is causing the error — it’s not ‘dplyr’ itself but rather one of its dependencies. The full error message should tell you which one.

Comment: Thank you! I tried multiple packages and none of it works, so I'm not sure which package is causing the error. The error I listed above is the full error message.